# Type hinting for array-like

Tags: python, numpy

What would be the correct type hint for a function that accepts an one dimensional array-like object? More specifically, my function uses `np.percentile` and I would like to 'match' `np.percentile`'s flexibility in terms of the kind of array it accepts (List, pandas Series, numpy array, etc.). Below illustrates what I'm looking for:

```py
def foo(arr: array-like) -> float:
    p = np.percentile(arr, 50)
    return p
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `numpy.typing.ArrayLike`:

```
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike

def foo(arr: ArrayLike) -> float:
    p = np.percentile(arr, 50)
    return p
```

Comment: Is there also a way to specify typed kinds of arraylike?